# Get the ok from a javascript alert in asp.net code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

1) I've an updatepanel in an aspx page containing a gridview and an asp.net button

2) The user select some griview's items and press the asp.net button to launch some CRUD stuff on the DB via code-behind.

3) Before to start this CRUD stuff a javascript alert must appear to ask: "are you sure to continue?"

4) When the user press "OK" on the alert then the code behind can continue to operate the CRUD stuff

I was able to implements the first three points, but I'm blocked on the fourth: how the hell I can trap in code behind the "OK" pressed in the alert javascript?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about you call confirm just 'before' you starting the crud?

To accomplish this, just include `onClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"` on the asp.net button.

---

As you asked here is a simple example using command:

ASP.NET

```
   <asp:Button ID="cmdRegister" runat="server" Text="Register"  OnCommand="cmdRegister_Command" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" CommandArgument="10"></asp:Button>
```

Code Behind:

```
  protected void cmdRegister_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
  {
    int argument = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    if (argument == 10)
    {
      //somework
    }
  }
```

Comment: In this way I can only show the alert. What I want is 1) to get the OK (NOT OK) value generated by the user pressing OK (closing) the alert 2) to pass this  value to the code behind so to proceed or not to operate the CRUD stuff.

Comment: In the current button you can include commandparamter and then get this value from Asp.net. The code above will guarantee that command event only will fire if "OK" button was pressed.

Comment: Please @Cleiton could you give me an example?

Comment: `CommandEventArgs` : welcome to my coding brain!!! Maaany many thanks Cleiton !!!